# GridView on click move image position

Tags: java, android

I am trying to move the position of two tiles in a grid view. The images are from this array

`int[] homeImages = {R.drawable.home_1,R.drawable.home_2,R.drawable.home_3,R.drawable.home_4,R.drawable.home_5,R.drawable.home_6};`

```
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                int first = position;
                int second = position;

                Toast.makeText(puzzleLayout.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
```

How do i go about getting the position of the first click and swap that image with the location of the second click ? Any help would be amazing thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1. try to use [this library](https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid)
2. Use [Drag and Drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) from android :

   `grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(new DragGridAdapter(items, getActivity()));`

....

```
grid.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            GridView parent = (GridView) v;

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            int position = parent.pointToPosition(x, y);
            if (position > AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {

                int count = parent.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    View curr = parent.getChildAt(i);
                    curr.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

                            boolean result = true;
                            int action = event.getAction();
                            switch (action) {
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                                break;
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                                break;
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_image_view_small_gallery_selected);
                                break;
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_image_view_small_gallery_unselected);
                                break;
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                                if (event.getLocalState() == v) {
                                    result = false;
                                } else {
                                    View droped = (View) event.getLocalState();
                                    GridItem dropItem = ((DragGridItemHolder) droped.getTag()).item;

                                    GridView parent = (GridView) droped.getParent();
                                    DragGridAdapter adapter = (DragGridAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
                                    List<GridItem> items = adapter.getItems();

                                    View target = v;
                                    GridItem targetItem = ((DragGridItemHolder) target.getTag()).item;
                                    int index = items.indexOf(targetItem);
                                    items.remove(dropItem);
                                    items.add(index, dropItem);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                                break;
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_image_view_small_gallery_unselected);
                                break;
                            default:
                                result = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            return result;
                        }
                    });
                }

                int relativePosition = position - parent.getFirstVisiblePosition();


                View target = (View) parent.getChildAt(relativePosition);

                DragGridItemHolder holder = (DragGridItemHolder) target.getTag();
                GridItem currentItem = holder.item;
                String text = currentItem.getFile().getAbsolutePath();

                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("DragData", text);
                target.startDrag(data, new View.DragShadowBuilder(target), target, 0);
            }
        }
        return false;
```

then

```
    public class DragGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private List<GridItem> items;

public DragGridAdapter(List<GridItem> items, Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DragGridItemHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new DragGridItemHolder();
    ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
    holder.image = img;
    convertView = img;
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (DragGridItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.item = items.get(position);
holder.image.setImageBitmap(items.get(position).getBitmap());
return convertView;
}

public List<GridItem> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```